# Python:I want to create loop which will count the attachments to save on folder

Tags: python, outlook

looking to create a loop for item variable in code that are attachments from targeted mails. But its not allowing throwing error 'restrict object'.

```
import win32com.client
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import datetime as dt

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)

# path = os.path.expanduser("~C:/Users\bhosale.siddhesh/Desktop/MACRO")
#today = dt.date.today()


for folder in root_folder.Folders:

   myfolder = root_folder.Folders['Daily Input Files']

Filter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = 'indices@nse.co.in'"
myMail = myfolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)

Item = myMail.GetFirst()
    for attachment in Item.Attachments:
    attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\Users\bhosale.siddhesh\Desktop\Work\x' + '\\'+ 
    str(attachment)) #Saves attachment to location


Item = myMail.GetNext()   
    for attachment in Item.Attachments:
    attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\Users\bhosale.siddhesh\Desktop\Work\x' + '\\'+ 
    str(attachment)) #Saves attachment to location

Item = myMail.GetNext()   
    for attachment in Item.Attachments:
    attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\Users\bhosale.siddhesh\Desktop\Work\x' + '\\'+ 
  str(attachment)) #Saves attachment to location
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `Restrict` method of the `Items` class returns an `Items` collection that represents the items from the original Items collection which match the filter. So, you need to iterate over all items in the collection and save attachments.

To cover all folders (with subfolders) you must iterate over all folders in Outlook recursively (a raw sketch in VBA):

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```

But the best way to is to use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class to find all items that have files attached and then only process them by saving attached files on the disk. The key benefits of using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the Store class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

To find all items that have attachments you can use the following condition (for example, the string is for VBA macros, but the property is the same for all programming languages):

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=1"
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Python programming. it would be really helpful if you can give example of code modification to be used in python.

Comment: I don't use Python, so I can't help you here.